# How do I resolve unmet dependencies when installing virtualbox 6.1 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dependencies

I am having an issue with installing virtualbox 6.1 using apt with Ubuntu 20.04 OS. I used this tutorial to get all the way to the last step with the command

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1
```

which is giving me an error of

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The apt-cache policy virtualbox-6.1 is this.

```
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan
  Version table:
     6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan 500
        500 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan/contrib amd64 Packages
     6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

It is still having the python issue it looks like

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

```
$ dpkg -l python
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================================================
rc  python         2.7.17-1     amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (Python2 version)
```

```
$ dpkg -l python3
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Architecture Description
+++-==============-==============-============-=========================================================================
ii  python3        3.8.2-0ubuntu2 amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
```

Comment: What are you getting `virtualbox` from?   I don't see those requirements in the virtualbox 6.1 packaged from Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/virtualbox https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/virtualbox  Why not use the Ubuntu packaged version?

Comment: I am using apt to get virtualbox

Comment: Please add `apt-cache policy virtualbox` to your question.   As per first comment, I'd recommend the default Ubuntu packaged version found in repositories, it's tested & you'll have less issues come upgrade time ...  It's also 6.1 too, so I don't see why you're opting to add 3rd party repositories.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: I have added the ```apt-cache policy virtualbox-6.1``` to the question @guiverc

Comment: *eoan* refers to Ubuntu 19.10, thus why it has the `python2` dependencies.  That package won't work on any release from 20.04 on (without a lot of messing about).  You should use a source built for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; I'd still recommend the default repository package (I've had no issues with it).   Are you using Ubuntu 20.04?  or Ubuntu 19.10 as per your last paste?

Comment: FYI:  The python2 *deps* are EOL; refer https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/ Ubuntu 20.04 LTS means the 2020-April release, which was naturally after 1-Jan-2020 and thus doesn't use the EOL python2.  You should not have added packages relating to an EOL release, nor be using the EOL 19.10 release.

Comment: How would I just use the default repository package. @guiverc

Comment: A simple `sudo apt install virtualbox` will install the Ubuntu repository (assuming 'multiverse' is enabled, see my first comment) version, however you've shown pastes that apply to EOL releases (19.10/eoan).  An `apt-cache policy virtualbox` will show what is available (version wise, if you've added other sources it may add other versions by default with that command, so you'll need to specify version you want).  I'm not currently using *focal* and your pastes don't match `rmadison` results (known issue if I recall correctly) so won't advise further as your pastes don't match online tools

Comment: This is a question and answer site. If you have an answer, post the solution below so that it is helpful to future visitors.  Don't add "fixed" or "updates" into the title. The title's purpose is to adequately describe your question in order to identify it among other questions. You can accept a solution if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*

wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian `lsb_release -sc` contrib" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

sudo apt instal virtualbox-6.1
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me. It still gives the same unmet dependencies for python error...

Comment: @guiverc, the reason for *not* using the virtualbox package from the ubuntu repositories has something to do with an issue in kernel 5.8. I'm not an expert here, so I'll point you to this bug for more info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1891916

Comment: @mamaluigie, did you remove `virtualbox-6.1` first using `sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*`?

Comment: @mamaluigie, This looks like an issue with installing python on your machine. Plese edit your question and add the outputs of `python --version`, `dpkg -l python`, `python3 --version`, and `dpkg -l python3` to your question.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen the bug; but as I'm not impacted by it (still have 5.4 kernel on my *focal* boxes) I've not encountered the issue & ignored it. Thanks.  (I note that bug has been reported as fix released...)

Comment: I had to add symbolic link `python -> python2` because I did not have `python`. In other words I had `python2 -> python2.7` and `python3 -> python3.8` but nothing for `python`