# Software Updater - The package system is Broken

Tags: dependencies, update-manager

In the course of trying to install VirtualBox, I managed to break the Software Updater package system. I did follow [this how to fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311222/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-when-installing-virtualbox-6-1-on-ubuntu-20/1311229#1311229) post in the course of doing that but I'm not sure what I did along the way.
At this point my goal is to restore the software updater. Virtual box is another battle.

This is my machine profile:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubu0850 5.4.0-59-generic #65-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 10 12:01:51 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 >GNU/Linux
```

This is what happens when I run software updater.

[image]

Additionally, when I run

```
$ sudo apt autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic but it is not installed or
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-34-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-40-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.8.0-40-generic but it is not installed or
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-40-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first link points to the image, instead of the post that you refer to.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install -f` ?

Comment: Post link is pointing to the same image not the actual web address. Anyway, have you tried, 'sudo apt update' ? what's the output? You might have added some repositories by using sudo add-apt-repository ?

Comment: Did you *"Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems"* ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1311427/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: please show also `sudo dpkg -P  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-34-generic  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-40-generic`

Comment: Hi All. Thanks for your  comments. For now It appears  McCafee was causing the issue. Uninstalling McCafee allowed me to run the software updater.   Once i reinstall it I will  try it again.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was McAfee. I had to remove it, run the software updater then reinstall it. The software updater appeared to work even after the re install of McAfee as well,  even though there was nothing left to install